# IBM DataConnect refine operations

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

The supported list of transformations in `IBM's ETL` service `DataConnect` in `Bluemix Cloud` are these ones here:  https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/using_operations.html#concept_h4k_5tf_xw

I have looked and looked but with no luck, what if I want to transform some of my data with an operation that is not included here? For example run custom code in a column and get some specific output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Connect does not currently support refine operations outside of those provided with the service. We are adding new features and functionality weekly, but if you have a specific operation in mind, please let us know.

I will find out for you if we have the ability to execute custom code on our roadmap.

Regards,

Wesley - IBM Bluemix Data Connect Engineering

Answer (score 0):

As Wes mentions above in the short term we will continue to add new data preparation and transformation capabilities to the service. Currently there is no extensibility that allows you to code new transformations.

In the longer term we are considering allowing users to edit/extend pipelines using languages like Scala and Python. We don't have a defined date for these new capabilities.

Regards,
Hernando Borda
IBM Bluemix Data Connect Product Manager